# Big O using a stack is it O(1)?

Tags: java, big-o

I trying to solve some algorithms problems. I have this one:

Write a method reverseWords() that takes a message as an array of characters and reverses the order of the words in place.

For example:

```
char[] message = { 'c', 'a', 'k', 'e', ' ',
            'p', 'o', 'u', 'n', 'd', ' ',
            's', 't', 'e', 'a', 'l' };
```

As a result we should get:

> steal pound cake

The suggested implementation was this one:

```
public static void reverseWords(char[] message) {

    // first we reverse all the characters in the entire message array
    // this gives us the right word order
    // but with each word backward
    reverseCharacters(message, 0, message.length - 1);

    // now we'll make the words forward again
    // by reversing each word's characters

    // we hold the index of the *start* of the current word
    // as we look for the *end* of the current word
    int currentWordStartIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= message.length; i++) {

        // found the end of the current word!
        if (i == message.length || message[i] == ' ') {

            // if we haven't exhausted the array, our
            // next word's start is one character ahead
            reverseCharacters(message, currentWordStartIndex, i - 1);
            currentWordStartIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

private static void reverseCharacters(char[] message, int leftIndex, int rightIndex) {

    // walk towards the middle, from both sides
    while (leftIndex < rightIndex) {

        // swap the left char and right char
        char temp = message[leftIndex];
        message[leftIndex] = message[rightIndex];
        message[rightIndex] = temp;
        leftIndex++;
        rightIndex--;
    }
}
```

As you can see it goes over the array twice, N + N so it would be O(n)

but I think of using a stack would be a better approach, something like this:

```
public static void reverseWords(char[] message) {
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
        String word = "";

        int i = 0;
        while (i < message.length) {
            if (message[i] != ' ') {
                word = word + message[i];
            }
            else {
                stack.push(word);
                word = "";
            }
            i++;
        }

        stack.push(word);

        int j = 0;
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            String wordStack = "";
            wordStack = stack.pop();
            for (i = 0; i < wordStack.length(); i++) {
                message[j] = wordStack.charAt(i);
                j++;
            }
            if (stack.size() > 0) {
                message[j] = ' ';
                j++;
            }
        }
```

In this case it goes over the array only one and insert and remove items from the stack and it is supposed to be O(1). I mean it would be also O(n) but the difference is that you go over the array only once.

What do you think? Am I right or not?

Thanks

Comment: You only go over the array once, but the work involved depends on the _size_ of the array, making it O(N) — it is directly proportional to the amount of data you have. (but I haven't studied your code to make sure)

Comment: As said @Stephen P, it's O(n) and even going over the array twice is O(n).

Comment: It goes three times actually, not two. First time is when he reverses the whole thing. Second time is when he goes over the reversed array and third time is when he reverses the subarray for each word.

Comment: You iterate the array once, then each word once. If you ignore the cost of the intermediate objects you create, then I suppose you could call it an O(N) solution. The elegance of the first solution is that it uses constant memory space, in practice it's probably much faster as well.

Comment: correspondingly stack solution goes through array twice: when words are pushed and when they are popped. btw, it would be much neater if he would use character stack instead of string stack, append every popped character to the prefix and output whenever space is popped.

Comment: I'd say the second solution is more like O(n^2), or close to that. Constructing the words in `word = word + message[i]` (which is an overkill) makes as many string append operations as there are non-space characters. Each append creates a new string object and is probably by itself O(n). If this is true, then the whole loop is approximately O(n^2) (less the number of spaces). Also, the second loop is nested (`while { for { ... } }`) which is a strong indication for O(n^2). If the message consists of one-letter words, then there are half as many words as characters, which also makes it O(n^2).

Comment: Whether the array is traversed 1, 2, or 3 times is irrelevant, O(2n) and O(3n) are still O(n) — the work performed grows in direct proportion to the number of elements. If you had a nested loop that had to traverse the whole array for each element _in_ the array that would be O(n^2) — adding one element increases the work by the whole size of the array, so it's proportional to the square of the size of the array.

Comment: @StephenP, not sure if this is addressed at me, but this is more or less what I said above. The second solution is definitely O(n^2) for some corner cases (e.g. when the message consists of many small words), because then the inner `for` loop runs nearly as many times as the outer loop (proportional to the length of the whole message). In case the String concatenation `word + message[i]` is O(n), which I suspect, but haven't checked, then it is always O(n^2). This part can be vastly optimized, however, since you don't need to concat on each iteration, just find the next space and substring.

Comment: @Mike - not addressed at you — I was mainly responding to earlier comments debating whether it goes through two times or three times; I'm saying that distinction doesn't matter to big-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is should be faster, but they both in O(n).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the second solution is faster?

Comment: I doubt the second solution is faster, building the strings that make up the words would require additional iterations over the characters. I imagine the first solution is faster, if not much faster than the second solution.

Comment: yes, I read it again @Jake, it's indeed the first solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't solve this task in O(1).

In order to reverse the words in the message (array of characters), you obviously need to go through the whole array at least once, and probably more than once, as we can see in the various solutions.

But you definitely cannot reverse all the words without actually reading the complete array to the end. Reading the array to the end is an O(n) operation, by definition, with `n` being the length of the array.

An operation is O(1) when the runtime (or the number of steps required) is constant, or at least does not depend on the length of the input. A method that reads its whole input cannot be O(1) with regard to the length of the input.

Note that the "with regard to..." part is very important - it does matter what the `n` means in an `O(n)`.

For example, searching for an element in a hash table (or HashMap, in Java terms) is generally regarded to be a O(1) operation, because it does not depend on the number of elements already in the map.
It does however very much depend on the length of the element to be searched - it needs to compute the hash value of this element, which requires going through the whole length of the element, so this is obviously an O(n) operation with regard to the length of the input.
However, since the length of the element itself is usually negligible compared to the potential size of the whole hashmap, this O(n) is irrelevant. And since searching in the hash map is indeed independent of the size of the map, the whole thing is regarded as O(1).

Also note that O(1) does not mean that the algorithm will be fast for every given input. It only means that the runtime is constant, not that it is low. Usually O(1) algorithms have high fixed costs and high constant factors which is acceptable for large inputs, but for small inputs an O(n) algorithm with a low fixed overhead may well be faster.

Taking the hash map example, if there are 5 elements in the map, and you want to check if the map contains a given value, it is much, *much* faster to go through all 5 elements, instead of using the generic algorithm - calculating the hash of the searched element and using it to predict where it should be stored in the map. This is also true with 10 or 50 elements in the map, but with 5 million, it's a different story, and with 5 billion it's a ***much*** different story.

Comment:   Mike, this is much better than the accepted answer.